# Where are VLAN tagged packets?

Tags: vlan

Are they only in trunk links between switches/routers' packets?

Is there any way an endpoint sees tagged VLAN packets? (containing VLAN tags) What if I an endpoint sends a tagged packet that corresponds or not to their VLAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag is required anytime a single link is carrying traffic for more than one VLAN. This excerpt from this answer provides more contexts:

[Why is VLAN tagging required?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35222/why-is-vlan-tagging-required/35229#35229)

> The real reason you need VLAN Tagging is to distinguish VLAN traffic
>   on a port where multiple VLANs can exist.
>
> An [access port](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vlans/#access_port) is a port which carries traffic for only one VLAN.
>   A [Trunk port](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vlans/#trunk_port) is a port which carries traffic for multiple VLANs.
>
> On Trunk ports, all the frames are still carried across the wire in
>   the form of `1`s and `0`s.  Something has to exist in order for the
>   sending switch to indicate to the receiving switch which `1`s and `0`s
>   belong to which VLAN. That *something* is a [VLAN Tag](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vlans/#tagged-untagged).
>
> The VLAN Tag will be added whenever a frame is crossing a trunk port
>   and removed when the other switch receives the frame. It will look
>   like this:
>
> [image: VLAN Tags being added and removed on Trunk Ports]
>
> You can read more about VLANs and how they work in [this article](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vlans),
>   and how to configure them on Cisco switches in [this article](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/configuring-vlans/).